# How do I fix the error in downloading brain.js

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I am trying to install the brain.js and ran into the error in my VSCode.
The following error is shown on my VSCode. I have tried multiple solutions but none of them work. Any help would be appreciated. Below is the error shown in my terminal.

```js
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/class/app/node_modules/gl
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/class/app/node_modules/gl/build'     
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/angle_common/angle/src/common/Float16ToFloat32.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/angle_common/angle/src/common/MemoryBuffer.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/angle_common/angle/src/common/angleutils.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/angle_common/angle/src/common/debug.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/angle_common/angle/src/common/mathutil.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/angle_common/angle/src/common/string_utils.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/angle_common/angle/src/common/tls.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/angle_common/angle/src/common/utilities.o
npm ERR!   AR(target) Release/obj.target/angle/src/angle_common.a
npm ERR!   COPY Release/angle_common.a
npm ERR!   COPY Release/obj/gen/angle/id/commit.h
npm ERR!   TOUCH Release/obj.target/angle/src/commit_id.stamp
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/common/event_tracer.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/AttributeMap.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/Buffer.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/Caps.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/Compiler.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/Config.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/Context.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/Data.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/Debug.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/Device.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/Display.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/Error.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/Fence.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/Framebuffer.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/FramebufferAttachment.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/HandleAllocator.o
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/class/app/node_modules/gl/build'      
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.17.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.4 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! (node:3918) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/class/app/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/class/app/node_modules/gl/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/class/app/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/root/.cache/node-gyp/16.17.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/root/.cache/node-gyp/16.17.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/class/app/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/root/.cache/node-gyp/16.17.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/class/app/node_modules/gl',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! ../angle/src/libANGLE/HandleAllocator.cpp: In constructor ‘gl::HandleAllocator::HandleAllocator()’:
npm ERR! ../angle/src/libANGLE/HandleAllocator.cpp:29:52: error: ‘numeric_limits’ is not a member of ‘std’
npm ERR!    29 |     mUnallocatedList.push_back(HandleRange(1, std::numeric_limits<GLuint>::max()));
npm ERR!       |                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../angle/src/libANGLE/HandleAllocator.cpp:29:76: error: ‘::max’ has not been declared; did you mean ‘std::max’?npm ERR!    29 |     mUnallocatedList.push_back(HandleRange(1, std::numeric_limits<GLuint>::max()));
npm ERR!       |                                                                            ^~~
npm ERR!       |                                                                            std::max
npm ERR! In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/algorithm:62,
npm ERR!                  from ../angle/src/libANGLE/HandleAllocator.cpp:12:
npm ERR! /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_algo.h:3467:5: note: ‘std::max’ declared here
npm ERR!  3467 |     max(initializer_list<_Tp> __l, _Compare __comp)
npm ERR!       |     ^~~
npm ERR! ../angle/src/libANGLE/HandleAllocator.cpp:29:43: error: expected primary-expression before ‘(’ token
npm ERR!    29 |     mUnallocatedList.push_back(HandleRange(1, std::numeric_limits<GLuint>::max()));
npm ERR!       |                                           ^
npm ERR! ../angle/src/libANGLE/HandleAllocator.cpp:29:52: error: ‘numeric_limits’ is not a member of ‘std’
npm ERR!    29 |     mUnallocatedList.push_back(HandleRange(1, std::numeric_limits<GLuint>::max()));
npm ERR!       |                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../angle/src/libANGLE/HandleAllocator.cpp:29:73: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
npm ERR!    29 |     mUnallocatedList.push_back(HandleRange(1, std::numeric_limits<GLuint>::max()));
npm ERR!       |                                                                         ^
npm ERR! ../angle/src/libANGLE/HandleAllocator.cpp:29:76: error: ‘::max’ has not been declared; did you mean ‘std::max’?npm ERR!    29 |     mUnallocatedList.push_back(HandleRange(1, std::numeric_limits<GLuint>::max()));
npm ERR!       |                                                                            ^~~
npm ERR!       |                                                                            std::max
npm ERR! In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/algorithm:62,
npm ERR!                  from ../angle/src/libANGLE/HandleAllocator.cpp:12:
npm ERR! /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_algo.h:3467:5: note: ‘std::max’ declared here
npm ERR!  3467 |     max(initializer_list<_Tp> __l, _Compare __comp)
npm ERR!       |     ^~~
npm ERR! make: *** [angle/src/libANGLE.target.mk:241: Release/obj.target/libANGLE/angle/src/libANGLE/HandleAllocator.o] 
Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/class/app/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/class/app/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/class/app/node_modules/gl
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.17.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-10-17T08_23_46_712Z-debug-0.log
```

How do I fix this? This error appears after I **npm install brain.js** in my VSCode.

Comment: the key error is probably `python: not found`

Comment: How do I fix that issue since I have downloaded Python in my computer and the error is still the same

Comment: "downloaded" ... and installed? on the command line does `python -V` output the version of python you "downloaded" - looks like you're using WSL, is that correct?

Comment: Hi I've installed Python in my computer and yes I'm using WSL

Comment: I've typed that and it showed me this: Command 'python' not found, did you mean:    
  command 'python3' from deb python3
  command 'python' from deb python-is-python3

Comment: perhaps install `python-is-python3` like suggested

Comment: It is still the same

Comment: so, after installing `python-is-python3`, the result of `python -V` is still `Command 'python' not found`? You must've done it wrong

Comment: Now it's showing me these after typing python -V: import 'copyreg' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fb788511ae0>
import 're' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fb7884c9ab0>
# /usr/lib/python3.10/__pycache__/token.cpython-310.pyc matches /usr/lib/python3.10/token.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3.10/__pycache__/token.cpython-310.pyc'
import 'token' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fb788511d20>
import 'tokenize' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fb7884ca5c0>....

Comment: really? python -V does that? (that's a CAPITAL V) it should just show the version and exit

Comment: Restarted my VSCode and now it is showing me this. Command 'Python' not found, did you mean: command 'jython' from deb jython (2.7.2+repack1-4)
Try: apt install <deb name>
I've ran the "apt install jython" in my VSCode command line and then restart. The error is still the same

Comment: why would you install jython? *Python seamlessly integrated with Java* - it really is odd that `python` isn't a symlink to `python3` after installing `python-is-python3` - what's the result of `ls -l /usr/bin/python`

Comment: oh, wait `Now it's showing me these after typing` is correct

Comment: `Command 'Python' not found` why is that Python? it should be `python` ... case is significant in linux

Comment: the result is this *lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Oct 11  2021 /usr/bin/python -> python3*

Comment: so why doesn't `python -V` work? (capital V not lower v) - after installing that package, have you tried installing `brain.js`?

Comment: After installing, these are the errors now: npm ERR! path /mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/class/app/node_modules/gl
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/class/app/node_modules/gl/build'
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/angle_common/angle/src/common/Float16ToFloat32.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/angle_common/angle/src/common/MemoryBuffer.o
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/angle_common/angle/src/common/angleutils.o

Comment: must be a lot more to it, why don't you edit your question and put the new error output in there

Comment: Alright. I've added in the output in my question.